# Safety from ajax bomb

Tags: ajax, security, javascript-injection

There are some servlets which I call from ajax to check user availability and some other work. An ajax request can be send only if user is login.

But the problem is, user can hit server through ajax call mass number of times in a second using javascript injections. It can make server down.

There is one possibility to control it;

1. If number of hits from same IP in a
   second(or some period) crosses the
   maximum limit then I can invalidate
   the session.

But some of my colleagues are not in favor of limiting the user. Is there any other way to safe my server from ajax bomb.

Comment: Your question is about Denial-of-Service attacks and as such it's much broader than AJAX alone. If you expect DoS attacks, your task is to protect the server itself from them, and not limit your protection with AJAX-related modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- you can **throttle** ajax requests, slowing them a little when they hit a limit, as some sites do.
- **rate limit** (completely block) the ajax request after X requests, as Twitter does with its API
- choose another option, like WebSockets.

These can be either server-sided or client-sided, server-sided being the obvious choice for security.

> But the problem is, user can hit server through ajax call mass number of times in a second using javascript injections. It can make server down.

Javascript injection is the least of your problems if you're concerned with your server staying alive. Raw HTTP DDoS attacks are a much bigger problem than a few ajax requests. The main thing Javascript injection should stick right in your mind is to do with security, not server uptime.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with some web app i have developed,
the solution i came up with was to check the referer on the server-side,
and only allow calls from the server (127.0.0.1).

Comment: In javascript injection, referer doesnt get changed.

Comment: lol, thats right... but i dont think you got how it works...
ONLY the server can call the ajax page...
if you will try to inject javascript to that page,
your referer IP would be your own IP, Not the servers local IP.

Comment: this could be a great help if it is so. Let me check... thanks